# Automatic Merge in TeamCity: how to specify which branch to watch if multiple VCS roots are used?

Tags: git, version-control, teamcity

I am trying to use `Automatic Merge` feature in TeamCity to automatically merge the dev branch to QA one. My build configuration uses multiple VCS roots.

How should I specify from which VCS root a branch should be picked in 'Watch builds in branches' field?
http://prntscr.com/985o0v

Answer (score 0):

The [logical branch name](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Logicalbranchname) should be specified in Automatic Merge build feature. Unfortunately there is no ability to configure where the logical comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Automatic Merge and it doesn't work as I need. So I created two configurations and dependency.